# How do you build your own calorimeter in your garage?

Tags: thermal-conductivity

I have seen people built their own calorimeter at home but when I messaged them, they didn't reply how exactly they did it. I want to try building one that is similar to [this one](https://www.linseis.com/en/our-products/differential-scanning-calorimetry/dsc-pt1600/) but I'm not sure how to do it. They had this one at the Uni I previously went to and I could use it for an upcoming project.